# I need to rescue my .php files from open directory

Tags: php, indexing, save

I have an open directory which does not have an index.html file. As you know, this is a bad idea as people can download my files. Luckily for me, I don't have access to the FTP anymore but I need a .php file I can see from the directory. Right clicking and saving it to my desktop results in a 0kb file. Why can I save an image, mp3, or other file from this directory, but not .php files?

Is there anything I can do??

EDIT: So it seems like I'll need to find a way to get FTP access to the directory or domain. I'll have to contact the host provider and do a password reset or some such

Comment: and this comment doesnt change that.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP doesn't actually let you download files directly. It just lets you send a request to the server, the server doesn't have to give you anything. Sometimes, these requests result in the server handing you a file, but in the case of php, the request causes the server to run the php and return the result.

So, no, there is nothing you can do via HTTP alone. You have to get access to the server in some other way (FTP, SCP, SSH shell, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

The web server that is serving the files is probably processing the php when you're trying to "save it". In order to obtain the files you'll need some kind of file access to the original directory.

Some servers do provide access to the php source via additional service, but you're more than likely not able to get that. You're stuck without the source. I'd contact your provider to get FTP and/or web file access.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP file is being executed. You cannot download the raw source code over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

PHP files are evaluated by the server before being sent to the browser. If the file you're trying to download doesn't produce any output, your browser will not be sent any and the resulting file will be 0 bytes in size. Images, mp3 files, and others are all downloaded and then evaluated client-side.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing you can do without FTP or some other direct access to the files. When you request a PHP file from the server over HTTP, it's configured to execute that file and display the result, not the file contents. There is no way to see the source code of PHP files on a properly configured server with direct HTTP access. I say properly configured because it's possible to change the mapping information in, for example, httpd.conf to prevent the server from executing the files, in which case you would see the actual file contents.